# How legit is it to ask & answer some questions about my favorite RPG system (that I have contributed some small material to)?

Tags: discussion, game-systems, self-promotion

I really like [*Legend*](http://www.ruleofcool.com/). I was a playtester for it, wrote them a review on RPG.net, and have since written some material of my own that has been included in their books (if it matters, I volunteered this work and was neither compensated nor expect to receive compensation should *Legend* take off).

I think the system’s pretty good. I know for a fact that even among people who know of it, there are a few pretty common questions that I could address pretty well I think. But I just don’t know how legitimate it is for me to start these kinds of questions, particularly when as far as I can tell, no one on rpg.SE has ever asked or answered anything about the system. I have no delusions that my interest in posting these questions is for the sake of getting some questions on it out there, maybe getting a *Legend* tag created, etc., because I like the system and hope to see it do well, hope to see more people playing it so I can get in on some games.

So, should I go ahead and ask & answer some questions about *Legend*, or is that too spam-like and/or promotional?

Comment: I just had a look at the legend home page and I am afraid to ask: is it alive and well or has it faded?

Comment: @KorvinStarmask Pretty well dead. The original group that worked on it has all moved on, and an entirely separate group that worked on a second edition exists but I don’t know much about it; not even sure if they still are. They certainly haven’t asked to put anything up on ruleofcool.com, though I suppose they might have their own site.

Comment: Related: [Is it good to use a Q&A to help other users discover a system?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9230/is-it-good-to-use-a-qa-to-help-other-users-discover-a-system)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Provided that asking/answering questions about Legend is not your only reason for being involved here, and is not the only contribution you are making. I think this is fine.

What I would advise is that you disclose your connection to Legend, probably at least in your answers.

Lastly, if you're going to ask and self answer, please make sure the questions are actually good and not just vehicles for the answer you really want to write :).

We're very happy to get coverage of small RPGs and as a contributer you qualify as an expert in Legend which is what we're here for.

Comment: Yes, very good point about the purpose of my account. No worries there; I also have a fair bit to say about D&D 3.x.

Comment: glad to hear it. btw have you read this section of the [faq#promotion]. that's a good place to get the general guidelines for promotion, although it doesn't speak to this specific case

Comment: Yeah, I've read that one, but thanks for the link (I read it on SO, so it's good to confirm that it's the same here).

Comment: Actually I don't think it should be a problem if you're only sticking to one system. After all, if I was only interested in 4e, nobody would come to me and say "Hey, so you're only answering 4e questions - that's a problem." The issue is whether what you're doing counts as being here just to promote a game. Being actually constructive in questions and answers about a game ought to be fine, as long as there isn't a concern you're here for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs it's a question of motivation.

Answer (score 7):

IMO, please do. having an answer that is semi authoritative is a good thing. I would only advise not asking questions that are only designed to lead into an answer you already know.

Comment: Hmm, on other SE sites, using the Q&A format to spread knowledge, even things you already knew, is encouraged. Is that not true with rpg.SE?

Comment: Wax Eagles answer clarifies this point I think. Just make sure you are not posting questions for the sake of getting the name out there.

Answer (score 3):

When determining if a question to which you know the answer is a good one, I would recommend drawing on actual play questions.

Rules questions that come up at the table and are not answered by means of "flip to the page and quote" would probably make for good content on a site like this.

Rules questions that can be easily answered from the books are less applicable as "expert" and "intermediate" questions, but they also have their place on the site. I would not discourage them, but also would consider their value before asking them.

- Questions that frequently come up are much more generally useful than questions that are rare.
- Questions that imply at least a passing familiarity with the game are better than ones that don't.

i.e. A D&D question about what does 3d6 mean is a bit lame, even if that were to always comes up when introducing new players to the game.

Comment: The question I asked & answered was “[Can you trade a slow track for a fast track when multiclassing in Legend?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/can-you-trade-a-slow-track-for-a-fast-track-when-multiclassing-in-legend)” While it is a question that can be answered just by pointing out the rule, I've seen it asked quite often; it seems people often miss that rule. I'd love your opinion on whether or not it was a good choice, to guide future questions I may put up.

Comment: I deliberately don't suggest avoiding the inverse style of questions - once that can be easily answered from the rules - as they also have their place here. Updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's an idea- you may be great at the system, but do you know anyone who isn't? Grab a few new players, start up a game, and any question that takes you more than a few minutes to figure out the answer would probably fit on the site. Ask the question they asked, and answer with your answer.

Comment: A great idea! Sadly, the game I was DMing was for a crew of players completely new to RPGs, and more unfortunately, that game died due to scheduling problems. But still, I'll see if they have any insight.

Answer (score -11):

If the questions were common, they'd be asked here already.  A lot of small and/or niche games pop up here naturally.  Astroturfing questions and answers don't particularly help anyone.

Comment: You're certainly welcome to your opinions, but I take offense at the accusation of "astroturfing" -- I took pains to make sure that my behavior was appropriate and that I was supporting a favorite game system in a manner that was acceptable and helpful. The positive feedback I've received from others suggests that the questions and answers I've asked *have* been helpful to at least a few.