# Trying to ask the moderator a question but don't have 20 rep to ping in general Chat. How do I PM the moderator?

Tags: discussion

[Last post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179273/62294) was deemed an advertisement by moderator. Not trying to place ads but see if anyone wants to play a new game we have. How can you do that without mentioning the name of the game? It is already published, just new and not as well known as DnD and other stuff you can mention. And just because it is OUR game, the mod sees it as self promotion. Should I log in as someone else and lie and say "Wow guys, I just learned of an awesome new game that isn't my own... let's play."

Not trying to be cheeky here, and didn't want to say all this in public here, but really, 20 rep just to talk on general chat to ping moderator? Come on.

Comment: You should definitely take the [tour] and read the [help].

Comment: Thank you @KorvinStarmast! Best response with Anagkai. Appreciate your comments greatly. Just trying to do things right on this forum per your rules, and keep messing it up!

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Taking tour now... thanks.

Comment: I added a link to the deleted post for context.

Comment: Sorry site mechanisms made a hurdle like this, but hopefully we've now gotten the chance to explain how as much as possible (KRyan's answer is very good). Do ask if you have any further questions about the site, though we have a fair bunch on it here on meta.

Comment: No - It was my fault not understanding the specific role this site has (and for somehow missing the tour at the beginning...). Thanks again and...you're not so evil... lol.

Answer (score 30):

The site doesn’t have any “private message” mechanism. This is very much by design. Luckily, site moderators are the one kinda-sorta exception: if you flag a post, one of your options is to send a message to a moderator. They can then initiate a private discussion with you.

**That would *not* be the recommended solution to *this* situation, however.**

Instead, you should learn a little bit more about who we are and what this site is about.

We don’t accept questions asking for interest in playing games here; that’s not what the site is about. We ban questions looking for groups, questions looking for GMs, and so on, too—in all cases, those just aren’t on-topic here. Questions can’t be open-ended like that, they have to be *actual questions* that can at least theoretically have *actual answers*. As in definitive, comprehensive, authoritative answers that can become a resource for future readers. Most of our site rules are geared towards encouraging these sorts of questions, and filtering out others which are better-handled on other sites. (By the way, we *do* have recommendations for [discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563), which may be more interested in hosting discussions of a new game with the game’s creators.)

Links to your game are acceptable *if and when it is appropriate content for an otherwise-valid question*. We also expect those who are related to a product to disclaim that affiliation, just so readers know what they’re getting. And if your *only* reason for being here, and only content you contribute, is about your game, you might also get the cold shoulder for that.

For example, when I first joined this site, I was at the time a writer and designer for Rule of Cool, working on their game Legend. Like you, I had similar interests in getting the word out about the game. But the way I handled this was to [start a meta discussion on the appropriateness of that](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1655/4563), which is where the site agreed that the best solution was, as I said, to only allow such posts if they are legitimate content we would otherwise allow, *and* such affiliations are disclaimed. See [wax eagle’s excellent answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1657/4563), which remains the community consensus to this day:

> Provided that asking/answering questions about Legend is not your only reason for being involved here, and is not the only contribution you are making. I think this is fine.
>
> What I would advise is that you disclose your connection to Legend, probably at least in your answers.
>
> Lastly, if you're going to ask and self answer, please make sure the questions are actually good and not just vehicles for the answer you really want to write :).
>
> We're very happy to get coverage of small RPGs and as a contributer you qualify as an expert in Legend which is what we're here for.

So please, join our merry band, take a look at other questions too, vote as you see fit, maybe answer a few. Self-answered Q&As are acceptable, but make sure they’re legitimately questions that real users might ask. In fact, the best way to handle it may be to point to your fans that this resource exists, and is a place where you’re answering questions—if they have actual questions for you, and you answer them, then those will make great answers and should be fairly well-received.

(Though don’t have your fans spam the site with every question they can think of just to give you an excuse to promote the game more—*that* would be **very** poorly received.)

Comment: Very much appreciate both answers. Thanks @Kryan for the time you invested in getting me on the right track. I was very excited finding this as I've enjoyed Role-Playing Games for over 40 years. I have a better understanding of the purpose of this site now, and will give helping answer questions a shot, not just our game. Thanks again!

Comment: Nicely done **and** experience-based to boot!  

Answer (score 13):

> Last post was deemed an advertisement by moderator. Not trying to place ads but see if anyone wants to play a new game we have. How can you do that without mentioning the name of the game?

You don't. Not here, anyway.

Basically, we are not a classifieds board. We aren't a forum; we're a Q&A site. This is not a place for posting ads for your games.

We are here to help people who have questions or problems relating to tabletop RPGs. To that extent, [we have questions from people asking about *how* to find other players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finding-other-players). Note this is also not a place to say “join my game”. It's instead a place to guide people through the process of *how* they will find other games.

If you want to contact a moderator the appropriate way to do that might be to raise a custom flag on your own question requesting moderator attention and explain. Note though we don't have a direct message system like KRyan mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a personal interest in something you wish to promote on these sites the most appropriate thing to do is put that something in your user profile. Then participate in the site like anyone else would. Create the content the site needs and the site will send curious people to your user profile page.